# Как можно чейнить контроллеры в spring?

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-boot, rest

Например, создаётся какая-то API-шка `v1`, путь к ней `/api/v1`. Я хочу сделать что-то вроде

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApiController {
    @RequestMapping("/v1")
    public ... v1Controller(какие-то аргументы) {
        Связь с UserController   /user
        Связь с CourseController /course
        ...
    }
    @RequestMapping("/v2")
    public ... v2Controller(какие-то аргументы) {
        Связь с UserController   /user
        Связь с CourseController /course
        ...
    }
}
```

То есть общая идея такая, что есть несколько контроллеров, которые обрабатывают разные эндпоинты, но у всех у них есть общая часть в RequestMapping, а именно `/api/vНОМЕР`. Хочется избавиться от этой части... Где-то прописать 1 раз и дальше пользоваться. Это вообще реализуемо здесь на базовом уровне? Или придётся писать каждый раз в маппинг `/api/vНОМЕР`?

Так как может не совсем быть понятным (так-как я пришёл из ноды), как вы выстраиваете роутинги? То есть в каждом контроллере прописываете full path? (аля `/api/v1/student/{id}`, вместо того, чтобы поднять 1 какой-то объект, в котором было бы `/api`, потом в другом объекте получать информацию по версии, а дальше уже выстраивать эндпоинты)

Comment: Что значит "чейнить контроллеры"? Вы хотите из одного запроса вызвать другой запрос? С возвратом?

Comment: @RomanC На "языке" ноды app.use("/api", ApiController). В ApiController app.use("/v1", v1Controller), app.use("/v2", v2Controller), app.use("/v3", v3Controller). И так далее. Тут, очевидно, может по-другому как-то выглядеть. То есть мне самое главное, чтобы можно было где-то пометить, что сейчас идёт /api, потом в другом классе/интерфейсе/аннотации подвязать, что /api надо соединить с /vНОМЕР и так далее

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу (и что позволяет спринг согласно этой [ссылке](http://www.kscodes.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-controller-extends-another-controller/)) то можно так сделать:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ParentController {
 
    @RequestMapping("/someAction")
    public String someAction() {
        return "someAction"
    }
}




@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class V1Controller extends ParentController {
 
    @RequestMapping("/someAction")
    public String someActionV1() {
        return "someActionV1"
    }
 
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v2")
public class V1Controller extends ParentController {
 
    @RequestMapping("/someAction")
    public String someActionV2() {
        return "someActionV2"
    }
 
}
```

Соответственно должно быть возможно теперь делать такие запросы:

`http://localhost:8080/<Project>/api/someAction`
`http://localhost:8080/<Project>/api/v1/someAction`
`http://localhost:8080/<Project>/api/v2/someAction`

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что это сработает только при работе с модельками. Я попробовал и, видимо, что-то не так сделал или так просто делать нельзя.

Comment: Но я пробовал с @RestController

Answer (score 0):

> есть несколько контроллеров, которые обрабатывают разные эндпоинты, но у всех у них есть общая часть в RequestMapping, а именно /api/vНОМЕР. Хочется избавиться от этой части... Где-то прописать 1 раз и дальше пользоваться.

Например можно прописать в `application.prolerties`:

```
v1API=/api/v1
```

далее используется springEL для того, чтобы добавить префикс к пути контроллера.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${v1API}")
public class ApiController {
...
```